# Page does not load in iFrame

Tags: html, iframe, http-headers

I am a bit puzzled why the following page does not want to load in an iFrame:
http://betting.betfair.com/betfair-announcements/betting-apps/automate-your-trades-on-betfair-140114-272.html. I have looked at the http header to see if there is some response that blocks it but I does see anything that points towards this.

Anyone has an idea whats going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are being blocked by the server, if you try it in chrome it will show you the error.

My dutch chrome error: "Verzoeken aan de server zijn door een extensie geblokkeerd."

Meaning: requests to this server are being blocked by an extension

Comment: Hi, it seems that the adblocker (AdBlock in my case) I am using also block the content from being loaded within the iFrame. Disabling the plugin made the page load for me.

Comment: Oh ye ofcourse! He thinks it's an ad... probebly because the url contains the word bet/betting

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why its not working for you, I did:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <iframe src="http://betting.betfair.com/betfair-announcements/betting-apps/automate-your-trades-on-betfair-140114-272.html" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

and posted no problem.

Comment: Hi, my adblocker was blocking the content from being loaded.

Comment: ahhhh that would do it